# Risks of custom domain for personal email address?

Tags: email, internet, spam-prevention, domain-name

I am not speaking of hosting the web server myself, I would delegate that to a well established company, for example the registrar I use for the domain name.

I want to know what the risks would be to having an email in the form something@custom-domain where custom-domain would be used only by me. Will I be able to reliably send email, or should I expect my outgoing emails to be blocked by spam filters ? i.e. do spam filters use allowlist for domains ?

Comment: I've been doing this for years, without a problem. As long as your hosting provider/mail service provider doesn't get themselves onto a blacklist for tolerating spammers, you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

> Will I be able to reliably send email, or should I expect my outgoing emails to be blocked by spam filters?

With proper configuration it should work reliably. There are other downsides though:

- If you're going to use aliases, it's easy to associate them
- You have to keep paying for that domain forever, otherwise someone else will be receiving your mail

Comment: Thanks for this input. I do not understand *If you're going to use aliases, it's easy to associate them*, do you mean: you may end up having too many aliases and it is a burden to maintain them ?

Comment: @GabrielDevillers You may have your mail configured to redirect all incoming mail to eg. `gabriel@devillers.name` and use different aliases for different purposes, eg. `superuser@devillers.name` just for this site. But a smart person will recognize that all emails on `devillers.name` probably go to the same inbox